# Cannot retrieve data sent by restfulwebservice in Java

Tags: java, ajax, json, eclipse, rest

I sent Json as post request from Javascript by restfulwebservice but the break point never breaks in Java file which is post type and consumes application/json

HTML:

```
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/RestfulInEMS/user/admin";      

    empJson = {Username:x[1],IdentityNo:x[2]};


        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);            
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xmlhttp.send(empJson);  
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {               
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
            var result= xmlhttp.responseText;           
        }
        }
```

JAVA:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void AddEmployee(JSONObj input)
//here JSONObj is class with data variables same as key name in JSON object sent
```

Comment: Are you getting any error (like 404 not found)? I suspect the webservice might not have been published. Open browser debugger and check what's the response you are getting when you call your service.

Also post your `web.xml`.

Comment: There are several levels involved in request mapping. File `web.xml` as underlined in previous comment, annotation `@Path` in your resource class, eventually annotation `@ApplicationPath` in your application class. We can't help you if we haven't all these elements. Thanks!

Comment: @PramodKarandikar  I tried debugging it breaks when i send string and set consumes to text/plain , but if i change to json it's not calling function and when i posted json from rest client it gave 415 error

Comment: What's the content type seen when you actually post the AJAX JSON request? Check in the browser debugger. Probably, it's always going as `text/plain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution :

Problem:

```
    xmlhttp.send(empJson);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {               
   if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        var result= xmlhttp.responseText;           
    }
    }
```

Solution:

```
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(empJson));
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {               
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
            var result= JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);           
        }
        }
```

**Explanation:

I need to convert it to string to pass as Json and used Jackson libraries for mapping it to class directly and while recieving it i recieve as text and use Json.parse to parse into a object.**